# fetch catch return Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

i try to throw error message but it throw me this message : (use React and NodeJS)

**return SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0**

```
   fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/register", options)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(user => {
                    alert('Registration successful !')
                    this.props.history.push("/"); 
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err)
                    console.log(err.message)
                });
            }
```

server side :

```
router.post('/', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const user = request.body;
        const newUser = await registerLogic.addUser(user);
        if (newUser === 0) {
            throw "User name already exists";
        }
        if(newUser === 1){
            throw "Something is missing";
        }
        response.status(201).json(newUser);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(500).send(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your response is not JSON so is throwing an error attempting to parse it. Check what the response of your API call is. If there is a scenario where it will not return JSON, check the content type header before attempting to parse it on the client.

Answer (score 4):

The error `Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0` tells you pretty much what's going on here: the first character of the JSON you’re trying to parse is literally a “U”.

Looking at your server-side code, you’re throwing an error “User name already exists”, catching that error, and then returning that message as the response body. Unfortunately, it's not valid JSON, hence the error.

Instead try returning a valid JSON response by updating your `catch` statement like this:

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (error) {
  response
    .status(500)
    .send(JSON.stringify({ error }));
}
```

Comment: Another reason to only throw actual errors and not arbitrary values.

Comment: @VictorNikiforov I included an example of one potential solution.

Comment: when i do it now it not get the catch and contine to .then and send me success message

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not json, in your catch block return json response.

```
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    response.status(500);
    response.json({ message: error.message })
}
```

In your fetch, check status code returned from the backend.

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/register", options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(user => {

    if (user.status !== 200) {
      alert('ERR', user);
      return;
    }

     alert('Registration successful !')
     this.props.history.push("/"); 
  })
   .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
      console.log(err.message)
    });
 }
```

Comment: thats work ty :) but not showing error .. in alert line it say : Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.  TS2554

Answer (score 0):

The other answers deal with your original issue well. To answer your followup questions

`when i do it now it not get the catch and contine to .then and send me success message`

Fetch will not reject the promise for failed HTTP status codes. This may be a surprise compared to Angular or jQuery which will. Fetch will only reject the promise for network level errors, connection dropped out etc.

This is stated in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

What you can do instead is something like this:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/register", options)
.then(async response => {
    if (!response.ok)
        throw new Error(await response.text());

    return response;
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(user => {
    alert('Registration successful !')
    this.props.history.push("/"); 
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
    console.log(err.message)
});
```

It will check for a successful HTTP status code and reject the promise chain with the server response if it was not. You may want to create your own exception extending the Error class rather than throwing it directly.

Comment: Great, please read through the `fetch` docs. It will explain all this behaviour which may seem strange at first glance. Will save you allot of time debugging!